# What does "packaging" of iPhone app mean?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone development. Once I found the term PACKAGING iPhone application.
I tried little googling but got no results.
Can someone give me an idea about what exactly "packaging" is iPhone development?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4, Build for Archiving. Once the project is built and archived, you'll find the archived version in the Organizer. From there, you can select the archive, validate it, and finally submit it to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean building a project, it's done automatically by [xcode](http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/Xcode/)
If you mean distributing your product, go and see the [appstore](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/)